# Entity Framework many to many duplicate value in join table when updating entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have following code first model:

```
public class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Master> Masters { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Slave> Slaves { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>().Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Slave>().Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>().Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Slave>().Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class Master : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Slave> Slaves { get; set; }

    public Master()
    {
        Slaves = new EntityHashSet<Slave>();
    }

    public Master(string name)
        : this()
    {
        Id = name.GetHashCode();
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Update(IEnumerable<Slave> slaves, Model1 model)
    {
        Slaves = new EntityHashSet<Slave>(slaves.Select(s => model.Slaves.CreateOrFind(s)));
    }

    public void Update(IEnumerable<string> slaves, Model1 model)
    {
        Update(slaves.Select(s => new Slave(s)), model);
    }
}

public class Slave : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Master> Masters { get; set; }

    public Slave()
    {
        Masters = new EntityHashSet<Master>();
    }

    public Slave(string name)
        : this()
    {
        Id = name.GetHashCode();
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I'm using the following utility classes:

```
public class EntityHashSet<TEntity> : HashSet<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    public EntityHashSet()
        : base(new EntityEqualityComparer<TEntity>())
    { }

    public EntityHashSet(IEnumerable<TEntity> collection)
        : base(collection, new EntityEqualityComparer<TEntity>())
    { }
}

public class EntityEqualityComparer<TEntity> : IEqualityComparer<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    public bool Equals(TEntity x, TEntity y)
    {
        return x.Id.Equals(y.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TEntity obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static TEntity CreateOrFind<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        return dbSet.Find(entity.Id) ?? dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

When I first add master entity to the database with the following code no error is thrown:

```
using (var model = new Model1())
{
    var m = new Master("master1");
    m.Update(new[] {"slave1", "slave2", "slave3"}, model);
    model.Masters.Add(m);
    model.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I try to use the update method for existing one, DbUpdateException is thrown:

```
var m = model.Masters.CreateOrFind(new Master("master1"));

m.Update(new[] {"slave1", "slave2", "slave3", "slave4"}, model);

model.SaveChanges();
```

> Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Relevant inner exception:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.SlaveMasters'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SlaveMasters'. The duplicate key value is (1928309069, -2136434452).
>   The statement has been terminated.

Why is this? I'm checking whether entities are already in the database or need to be created via CreateOrFind.

EDIT: To clarify, the line that produces the error is:

```
Slaves = new EntityHashSet<Slave>(slaves.Select(s => model.Slaves.CreateOrFind(s)));
```

Error is thrown when calling SaveChanges().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a dirty way of getting around this. Before I create new EntityHashSet I call raw SQL command deleting entries from SlaveMasters table that contains current master Id.

```
model.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM SlaveMasters WHERE Master_Id = " + Id);
Slaves = new EntityHashSet<Slave>(slaves.Select(s => model.Slaves.CreateOrFind(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I postpone you must be use the previous ef config file ,so it will  always try to insert the same value but update .
you could update or check your  ef  config file before update.

Comment: What do you mean by "ef config file"?